# Having some kind of expression in XML Config file

Tags: java, xml

I am very new to xml, is there a way, I can have some kind of
expression defined in xml, so that it could be interpreted properly in
java.

I have  a config file and I want to define some kinda of expression
i.e `#{age > 27 or location != US }` so that when it is parsed it would
be interpreted properly.

If there is any example, it would be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "interpreted properly"? You want java to interpret as code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring there's a way of doing something like this. You can basically put code in to special expressions. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html#expressions-beandef

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if there is a way to get the XML parser to do that, then the answer is no.

Your alternatives are to do the "interpretation" before you try to parse the XML (i.e. in some kind of preprocessor), or after you've parsed the XML (i.e. in the Java code).

jjathman mentions Spring expression language.  This is one approach to doing expression evaluation in Java code, but I don't know if it can be applied prior to parsing for XML.

The description of Spring expression language that jjathman linked to is focussed on EL in wiring files.  What happens there is that expressions are treated by the XML parser as text, and the Spring bean infrastructure does the expansion of the expressions at a later stage.  Unless your XML is Spring bean definitions, that particular description is not directly applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Import Groovy jar in your classpath and use Eval.xy method.

```
assert true == Eval.xy(30, "US", ' x > 27 or y != US')
```